# Enable/Disable button when image has been uploaded

Tags: php, ajax

Hi im uploading images to the server.  My upload button are active always and i use simple ajax code to upload the image without page referesh.How to enable the a select button after the image has been uploaded.the java script code i have posted here...

```
<!--AJAX UPLOADING SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#photoimg').live('change', function(){
    $("#preview").html('');
    $("#preview").html('<br /><img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview'}).submit();
});
});
});
});
///To enable/disable the language button depending on the image upload.      
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#language").attr('disabled',true);
  $("#language").change(
    function(){
      if ($("#PerformOcrForm").ajaxForm({target: '#previewText'}).submit()) {
          $("#language").removeAttr('disabled',false);
      }
      else {
          $('#language').attr('disabled',true);
     }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you have duplicate `});` too many times...

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the code for errors using firebug? If there is a bracket miss-match then normally the js just falls over.

Comment: Aside from pushing firebug, you can see the javascript console in all modern desktop browsers. It will show you where you're going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Pls try firebug for the see the error of brackets.

Comment: you cannot throw a statement like this. please be specific.